# jQuery works inside first panel but not duplicate panels

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following dropdown that works fine with my jquery on the first panel its produced but the same panel can be produced more than one times and subsequent pages the jQuery doesn't work for showing the other box.

e.g. and you will see in the code panel22_0 ...panel22_1 etc..

I'm puzzled now. Any help much appreciated.

panel22_

```
<xsl:for-each select="bankguarantees/bankguaranteedata">
    <div id="panel22" class="panels">
    <xsl:attribute name="id">panel22_<xsl:value-of select="@id"/></xsl:attribute>
  <table border="1" width="100%" height="100%"  bgcolor="#CECFFF" style="border-top: none" cellspacing="10">    
<tr>
<td>
<table border="0" width="100%" height="100%" bgcolor="lightyellow" class="inline">
<tr>
<td colspan="3" class="Header" height="1"></td>
</tr>
   <tr name="contliab" id="contliab">
        <script type="text/javascript">
         $('#producttypes').change(function()
         {
           if($('#otherprodtype').is(':selected'))
           {
           $('#otherprodtypebox').show();
           }
         else
          {
           if($('#otherprodtypebox').is(':visible'))
           {
             $('#otherprodtypebox').hide();
           }
          }
         });;
        </script>
        <td class="Label">Product Type</td>
        <td class="field">
         <select name="producttypes" id="producttypes">
          <option value="interventionguar">
           <xsl:if test="producttypes/option[@id='interventionguar']='selected'">
            <xsl:attribute name="selected"/>
           </xsl:if>Intervention Guarantee</option>
          <option value="customsguar">
           <xsl:if test="producttypes/option[@id='customsguar']='selected'">
            <xsl:attribute name="selected"/>
          </xsl:if>Customs Guarantee</option>
          <option value="otherprodtype" id="otherprodtype">
           <xsl:if test="producttypes/option[@id='otherprodtype']='selected'">
            <xsl:attribute name="selected"/>
           </xsl:if>Other</option>
         </select>
         <input class="amdInputText" type="text" id="otherprodtypebox" value="" style="display:none;">
            <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="otherprodtypebox"></xsl:value-of></xsl:attribute></input>
        </td>
       </tr>
```

Comment: You cant use the same ID of an element more than once on a page ;). Use a class instead.

Comment: are you suggesting adding a class in here <option value="otherprodtype" id="otherprodtype"> as in <option value="otherprodtype" id="otherprodtype" class="mybox"> ?

Comment: Technically you can use the same ID but you really shouldn't and jquery enforces this by only returning the first element if you do `$("#otherprodtype")`. You can get round it with `$("[id=otherprodtype]")` tho

Comment: @topcat3 I think he means change it to `class="otherprodtype"` and don't set an id unless you can make it unique (otherprodtype_1, otherprodtype_2 etc).

Comment: IDs should be unique on a page. Classes can be used as many times as you like.

Comment: @Rhumborl tried yours but didn't work. I'll trying giving it a class now. Its strange because as the panels are duplicated they will have the same id's but it doesn't seem to affect anything but the ones I'm doing jQuery on. Give me 20 mins :)

Comment: Using multiple divs with same name is against standards. Will get You to some kind of trouble someday ;).

Comment: the div panels are incremented though <div id="panel22" class="panels">
    <xsl:attribute name="id">panel22_<xsl:value-of select="@id"/></xsl:attribute>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use every ID only once in html.
Use class instead:

```
$('.producttypes').change(function()
     {
       $this = $(this);
       if($this.children('.otherprodtype').is(':selected'))
       {
       $this.sliblings('.otherprodtypebox').show();
       }
     else
      {
       if($this.sliblings('.otherprodtypebox').is(':visible'))
       {
         $this.sliblings('.otherprodtypebox').hide();
       }
      }
     });;
```

Of course you need to add producttypes class to elements with id producttypes, otherprodtype class to elements with id otherprodtype etc. Than You could throw away ID's so they dont repeat.

Comment: I tried this and it works on first screen but then the box is already appearing on screen two and later screens when it should be hidden unless other is selected from dropdown. Puzzled

Comment: it seems when i select other on the first screen it will be appearing on any subsequent screens but if I don't select other on first screen it wont appear on subsequent screens

Comment: Now should work better. Also - can You provide a link to a test site to see whats wrong?

Comment: I'm afraid its a bit tricky to put on a test site. basically is a wizard with steps created in xsl. You select the options and it creates panels. so pick 4 of one products and you'll get 4 of the exact panels with my code above. I might abandon using jquery and opt for a javascript solution if it works. tried your latest code but it doesn't work for me. box never appears

Comment: Without entire code and its structure cant help more. There have to be a problem with finding correct elements with jQuery, but I'm not quite sure, how they coresspond to eachother in dom tree.

Comment: It seams that othertypebox is outside .producttypes and .otherprodtype. Try the code now.

Comment: thanks for help. it seems it uses the code on first panel and then not again. I'll have to work through it. I'll accept your answer though. thanks for the effort.

Comment: Maybe I could still help. Could You describe your DOM with key elements ant their chierarchy? Only important ones are needed.

Comment: I will get this for you in the morning. Its basically as you see in above code. different panels are created and assigned a number after panel22_ . so panel22_0 panel22_1 etc..  The problem is it executes jquery for panel22_0 but then not for the rest. So I really need to increment my id or class value to make them different and to cater for this in the jquery too

Comment: Those panels are generated as result of a server side script, or they are added dynamically? Ps...  Maybe Yu can recreate mockup in jsfiddle?

Comment: Also, what I just have figured out - when panels are replicated, so is the js code inside, a nd that is not what should be done. Is it possible to put jquery in a separate file and load it in header?

Comment: I had tried javascript in the head and will leave it there but same result. Tried to create jsfiddle but lots of difficulty with the xsl. The panels are created with xsl e.g. if 3 products selected then you get panel22 three time. panel22_0 , panel22_1, panel22_2 . My code would prob work if I could increment the otherprodtypebox id to change to otherprodtypebox_0 , otherprodtypebox_1 etc and change the jquery to represent this. There can be a maximum of 99 products

Comment: I started a seperate question as I see it more relates to my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14277253/get-xsl-value-in-javascript-and-check-for-0-to-99