# get xsl value in javascript and check for 0 to 99

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xslt

I have the following xsl panels that are created depending on the user selecting a product. The user can select a maximum of 99 and 99 exact panels of the code below will be produced. I have jQuery code to manipulate (show/hide) an input field when 'Other' is selected from the dropdown.

Basically I'm trying to grab the xsl id in my javascript so I can apply the code to my id's which will be incremented accordingly.

Any help much appreciated. The errors relate to illegal argument in the javacript.

```
<xsl:attribute name="id">panel22_<xsl:value-of select="@id"/></xsl:attribute>

<table border="0" width="100%" height="100%" bgcolor="lightyellow" class="inline"
<script type="text/javascript">
var one = document.getElementById('<xsl:value-of select="@id"/>')
$('#producttypes' + '_' + one).change(function()
{
    if($('#otherprodtype').is(':selected'))
    {
    $('#myotherbox').show();
    }
    else
    {
    if($('#myotherbox').is(':visible'))
    {
    $('#myotherbox').hide();
    }
}
});;
 </script>

<tr>
<td class="Label">Product Type</td>
<td class="field">
    <select name="producttypes" id="producttypes_<xsl:value-of select="@id"/>">
        <option value="domguar">
            <xsl:if test="producttypes/option[@id='domguar']='selected'">
                <xsl:attribute name="selected"/>
            </xsl:if>Domestic Guarantee</option>
        <option value="indemnity">
            <xsl:if test="producttypes/option[@id='indemnity']='selected'">
                <xsl:attribute name="selected"/>
            </xsl:if>Indemnity</option>
        <option value="domcontbond">
            <xsl:if test="producttypes/option[@id='domcontbond']='selected'">
                <xsl:attribute name="selected"/>
            </xsl:if>Domestic Contract Bond</option>
        <option value="perfbond">
            <xsl:if test="producttypes/option[@id='perfbond']='selected'">
                <xsl:attribute name="selected"/>
            </xsl:if>Performance Bond</option>
        <option value="interventionguar">
            <xsl:if test="producttypes/option[@id='interventionguar']='selected'">
                <xsl:attribute name="selected"/>
            </xsl:if>Intervention Guarantee</option>
        <option value="customsguar">
            <xsl:if test="producttypes/option[@id='customsguar']='selected'">
                <xsl:attribute name="selected"/>
        </xsl:if>Customs Guarantee</option>
        <option value="vatbond">
            <xsl:if test="producttypes/option[@id='vatbond']='selected'">
                <xsl:attribute name="selected"/>
            </xsl:if>VAT Bond</option>
        <option value="otherprodtype" id="otherprodtype_<xsl:value-of select="@id"/>">
            <xsl:if test="producttypes/option[@id='otherprodtype']='selected'">
                <xsl:attribute name="selected"/>
            </xsl:if>Other</option>
    </select>
    <td class="field" id="myotherbox_<xsl:value-of select="@id"/>" style="display:none;">
    <input class="amdInputText" type="text" id="otherprodtypebox" value="" style="display:none;">
          <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="otherprodtypebox"></xsl:value-of></xsl:attribute></input>
    </td>
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have your problems in the following line

```
<select name="producttypes" id="producttypes_<xsl:value-of select="@id"/>">
```

And also in the associated table cell

```
<td class="field" id="myotherbox_<xsl:value-of select="@id"/>" style="display:none;">
```

This is obviously not valid XSLT syntax. But panic ye not, there is an straight-forward way to do this, and that is to use Attribute Value Templates. Just change your select statement to this

```
<select name="producttypes" id="producttypes_{@id}">
```

The curly braces indicate this is an expression to be evaluated, rather than output literally. Hopefully it should be output like so (assuming @id is set to 123, for example)

```
<select name="producttypes" id="producttypes_123">
```

You would amend the table cell in a similar manner.

Answer (score 0):

The below function worked with a combination of incrementing id's and an onchange button. Thanks for help

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myOtherBox(e, id) {
if (e.value == 'otherprodtype')
{
    $('#myBox_' + id).toggle();
}
}
```